# How to download English translation of BORI CE Mahabharat?

Tags: mahabharata, translation-request, translation

Bori's Critical Edition  of Mahabharat is available in Sanskrit only. I want it in English.

Where I can download the English translation of BORI Mahabharat?

Comment: Bibek Debroy has translated the BORI Critical Edition into English. You can buy the translation.I am not sure if the translation is available on  line.

Comment: I don't think we should be asking for the download link of a copyrighted book on any of the SE sites. See [this](https://hinduism.meta.stackexchange.com/a/502/2995) meta post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

BORI CE Mahabharata by [Bibek Debroy](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1aAPhp3vviqrbCBghpxpay-fuwNn-PTpn/view) is available on Google drive. One can also download it from [archive.](https://archive.org/details/TheMahabharata_201707)